# Script to automatically connect to different a vpn daily

Tags: bash, cron, openvpn

I want to know if there is a better way to connect to a different VPN server every 24 hours.  I am using NordVPN which relies on OpenVPN. My idea was to use crontab to run it daily.  But I want to make sure that previous VPN connection is closed prior to connecting to the next. This is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
if pgrep openvpn; then
    pkill -f -9 openvpn
    pkill -f -9 nordvpn
    sleep 5s
    echo "VPN Connection is closed"
    echo "Connecting to New Server"
    cd "/etc/openvpn/ovpn_udp"
    openvpn --config `ls us* | shuf -n 1` --auth-user-pass /path-to/nordvpn/password.txt
    sleep 5s
else
    echo "Connecting to NordVPN"
    cd "/etc/openvpn/ovpn_udp"
    openvpn --config `ls us* | shuf -n 1` --auth-user-pass /path-to/nordvpn/password.txt
    sleep 5s
fi
```

Then I would place this script into /etc/rc.local to start on boot and /etc/cron.daily to have it run daily.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html) allows you to use `--remote-random` feature, which allows the connection to randomly chose a server to connected to each time it is connected.

Thus you can simply run cron to reconnect the OVPN without having the needs to check if the connection is on or not.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Does it allow you to choose US servers only?

Comment: No, you can use any IP there, as long as they have same certs